# MaxLength decorator is not working with int.MaxValue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, custom-attributes

Given this basic GET method:

```
public Foo Get([FromQuery][MaxLength(int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage ="Custom error message")] int input)
{
   // DO THINGS
}
```

The `MaxLength` decorator is not working when I actually send a value bigger than `int.MaxValue`:

```
https://apiurl/foo?input=9999999999999999999
```

I get a `System.OverflowException: 'Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.'`, way before it reaches the MaxLength validator, in `System.Private.CoreLib`

Is there an easy way to handle this error and actually return my custom Error Message or do I have to implement a custom ModelBinder?

Comment: MaxLength is for strings and arrays, isn't it?

Comment: Probably you need to use [`RangeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=net-6.0). Or develop custom Max attribute.

Comment: @YongShun no, it doesn't work either. It doesn't reach the Attributes, the exception is thrown before

Comment: WIthout a ModelBinder I would try to implement a model class with just the one property as string. Implement IValidatableObject on that class and check for all those cases you want to. You could try to go for a string and a combination of StringLength and Regex Attribute instead of a modelclass but presumably won't fit well and makes your endpoint signature unreadable.

Comment: Model Validation lets you assert restrictions from that which your model would allow if just using the bare data types. It doesn't try to do anything about things that *cannot be represented in your model at all*.

Answer (score 1):

Create an custom attribute:

```
public class CustomNameAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is BadRequestObjectResult badRequestObjectResult)
            if (badRequestObjectResult.Value is ValidationProblemDetails)
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Error message");
            }
        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Then add it to your method:

```
[CustomName]
public Foo Get([FromQuery]int input)
{
   // DO THINGS
}
```